# How to show pictures in my UI working with vaadin

Tags: java, image, spring-boot, vaadin

I´m simply trying to show a picture in vaadin layout and I´m working with vaadin 13.

I´m not sure where the problem is. I checked many times the path of my picture and if it is in the right package or not, but everything seems right. 
So I can´t understand why it´s not displaying my picture.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Route(value = "", layout = MainView.class)
public class Overview extends VerticalLayout {

public Overview() {
    Label helloLabel = new Label("Hello User!");

    // Html img = new Html("<img src='/images/homePicture.jpg'>");
    // add(img);
    Image i = new Image("images/homePicture.jpg", "Alternative image text");
    add(i);


    Button secondButton = new Button("show");
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.add(i);
    secondButton.addClickListener(event -> dialog.open());
    add(secondButton);
```

Actually it´s looking like that.
[image]

File path structure:
[image]

Comment: hello, where is your `frontend` folder? Please try adding a folder called `frontend` between resources and images.  or if that doesnt work follow this guide more closely: https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-10-and-static-resources

Comment: @KasparScherrer Hello Kaspar, thanks I did but it´s still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved thanks to @KasparScherrer

When I changed my src/main/resources folder to src/main/webapp it works, but then my maven project is telling me that my project is missing the required src/main/resources folder.